# ajax call returns true after returning false and form submits

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having a function that returns true or false to submit a form via ajax

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
</form>

function validate(){
  var n = $("#user").val();
  if(n.length<2){           
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/checkuser.php',
            global: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {user:n},
            async: false, //blocks window close
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.trim().indexOf('exists')>-1){
                    alert('user exists);
                    return false;
                }
                else if(data.trim().indexOf('ok')>-1){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when I press ESC and check the Net via console i find the ajax request returning 'exists' and the alert of 'user exists' is fired but the form gets submitted while it shouldn't submit

[image]

Comment: You mean the entred user length<2 and the form submited? BTW you're missing a single quote in `alert('user exists);`.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki just a mistype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not working right now because you are not returning the `false` response to your form but your ajax success callback.

Please try the updated following code snippet:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
</form>

function validate(){
  var retValue = false;
  var n = $("#user").val();
  if(n.length<2){           
        retValue = false;
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/checkuser.php',
            global: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {user:n},
            async: false, //blocks window close
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.trim().indexOf('exists')>-1){
                    alert('user exists);
                    retValue = false;
                }
                else if(data.trim().indexOf('ok')>-1){
                    retValue = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
return retValue;
}
```

Comment: i have add same logic in my ajax but after retValue true form has been not submit.. can you help me

Comment: Please check for errors in your browser console. Your code most probably throwing error which is stopping the submission of the form.

In case you find no errors in console, consider uploading the code chunk where you having issues.

Happy to Help!

Comment: I have used same code but retValue does not get assigned value true. So form not getting submitted even if it meets requirement. There is no errors here. Also in console my function is returning success function data.